# Adding marker to the line to show trend matplotib python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have tried to plot the lines on the graph. But I am not understanding how I can place the marker on it. See the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(21,7))
plt.plot(datasetTest.closeTarget,label='Price',color='blue')
plt.plot(datasetTest.predict_close,label='Predicted',color='red')
plt.title('Price vs Predicted')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

I got the following output correctly:
[image: output]

I am willing to have the following markers on both the lines for every point for conditions. See the same image:
[image: required]

I have read the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html, but do not understand how to use it. Please let me know.

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand ;). I what you want simply `plt.plot(..., marker='o')` or is your question on how to customise their appearance?

Comment: Customization obviously. Because when I tried `marker="o"` it was on all over the line. I just want that up arrow or market when the point is up and down when it is down.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot([1,3,2,5,5,32,5,3,14], label='Price', color='blue')  # dummy data
plt.plot([1,5,2,4,2,53,3,4,24], label='Predicted', color='red')  # dummy data
plt.plot(0, 0, '^', color='green')  # tick 1
plt.plot(0, 2, 'v', color='red')  # tick 2
plt.plot(1, 2, 'v', color='red')  # tick 3
plt.plot(1, 6, '^', color='green')  # tick 4
plt.title('Price vs Predicted')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

You would have to figure out where on the x-y plane you want to plot the ticks, but I have plotted 4 as an example with different colors.

**Result**

[image]